# Regex pattern - match word that starts with @

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

My mobile application is just like a forum on mobile platform (WP7, Silverlight, .NET). One feature consists in tagging other users by writing "@" char followed by the username.

On server side, PHP, I'm parsing the text so that it matches tags and replace them with more readable string such as `[tag](display name)|(user id)[/tag]`, but that's not important for our purpose.

In order to match tags, I'm replacing all special chars with a space so I can prevent this like `.... @name, ....`. Then I'm removing all multiple spaces that the previous command could have been created. And finally I'm splitting each whitespace and then I check if that word begins with "@" char.
This is not of course the best method, but It's what I managed to do so far. There's a weak point, new line chars make my code fail. For example:

```
Hello, this is my first line
since I go to second and then I tag
@Jonh
who is a good boy
```

In case like this, the code I'm going to write below fails.
Where `$resp` is the text to parse.

```
if (strpos($resp,'@') !== false) {
    $new_str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ \@]/', ' ', $resp);
    $new_str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $new_str);

    foreach(explode(' ', $new_str) as $word)
    {
        if (strpos($word, '@') === 0) {
            //found my tag!                 
            }

        }   
    }
}
```

What would you advise to do?

Comment: What's the expected output ? Also you could change your first regex with `[^a-zA-Z0-9_ @]+` and remove entirely your second regex. Anyways +1 :)

Comment: Give a look to OGHaza's answer, it works

Comment: Well I wanted to know the expected output. I know it works that's why I upvoted it. The replace tag is a bit misleading here ...

Comment: Well, the output should be the string between @ char and a special char such as comma, whitespace and new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using regex to replace everything you don't want to match, you should be able to immediately match any word with an @ before it.

```
$subject = "..blah.. @name, ..blah..@hello,blah";
$pattern = '/@\w+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => @name [1] => @hello ) )
```

`/@\w+/` assumes that only numbers, letters and underscores (thats what the `\w` matches) are valid matches (i.e. @user123_xd), if you want to include for example the `-` (dash) in valid matches (e.g. @user1a-12) then the $pattern would be `/@[\w-]+/`

Comment: That's it. However, I'm not able to cycle through the list of matches. MatchCollection is an array of strings, isn't it?

Comment: `$matches[0]` in the code is the array of (strings) matches. `$matches[0][0] = '@name'; $matches[0][1] = '@hello';`.

Comment: I forgot to specify in which array it has to look into ( [0] ). Thank you for your help!

Comment: **NOTE:** In hindsight `\B@\w+` would have been a better regex in that it avoids matching an `@` in the middle of a word.