# RegEx finish after whole word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Soo I've got a problem. With my RegEx code. So I try to make a notification system and want to make it more visual. My problem with the code I worked out yet, is that it works, but only as long as you have a space in it. If you dont have that it will not work. So `'@test '` will work but not `'@test'` or `'@test.'`, how do I make RegEx stop after the word was found?

```
$str = preg_replace("/@(.*?) /", '<span class="label label-default">$1</span>', $str);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915129/regex-pattern-match-word-that-starts-with?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace a single piece of string that does not contain any spaces, use

```
@\S+
```

If you only want to allow letters, use:

```
@[a-zA-Z]+
```

And if you also want to allow digits, use:

```
@[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Depending on which option you prefer, your PHP becomes something like:

```
$str = preg_replace("/@([a-zA-Z]+)/", '<span class="label label-default">$1</span>', $str);
```

**Explanation**

- `\S` means one character that is not a white-space character
- `[a-zA-Z]` is a character class that allows any characters in the ranges `a-z` or `A-Z`
- The `+` quantifier means "one or more" of the preceding token or group

Comment: This would also match the `@test.` case. Perhaps using `\w` instead would be better.

Comment: You still have the trailing space in the regex pattern noted by Braj.

Comment: FYI Added an option in cast you only want letters.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thanks for your thoughtful comment. I'm not entirely sure I understand what he wants to match, so added other options.

Answer (score 1):

> I worked out yet, is that it works, but only as long as you have a space in it. If you dont have that it will not work

because you have an extra space in your regex pattern

```
/@(.*?) /
      ^^^
```

---

> how do I make RegEx stop after the word was found?

You can use `/@([a-zA-Z]+)/` for upper and lower case letters match only.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you search for "not a space" multiple times ?

```
/@[^ ]+/
```

Also, `*` means 0 to infinity times. So no need of the `?` in `.*?`